# Searching the required field in sql using VBA access 2010

Tags: sql, vba

I have one combobox with "Greater then","Less then" and "Equal to" value and I am putting some value in a textbox like "1200" then I want that if I select "Greater then" from the combo box then the result which I should get from the database will be greater then 1200.

I tried to search the same using LIKE "%",but I was failed.

Please tell me the code that how I can search the same written in vba using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to set up in a dynamic SQL query an equality, right?
Then, to do so, please keep in mind the following:
a) In the combo box, the conditions must be set together with an equality in an string variable containing that equality. It means that, when cboSomeCondition is changed, it must also set a strVarEquality with the equality you want. If someone choose "Greater than" in the cboSomeCondition, you must set the variable strVarEquality to ">". The same for the rest of the conditions - "Less than" -> "<" and "Equal to" -> "=" 
b) In the variable that sets up the SQL String (I am not sure what type of connection you are using, but I am supposing here an ADO with the ConnectionString set up), and considering txtValueTobeEvaluated as the field with the value to be compared against the values in the database, you just put it like this:
*(someAdoDBConnection).(someSQL)="SELECT field_a,field_b,field_c FROM table_x WHERE field_a " & strVarEquality & " " & txtValuetoBeEvaluated*

I hope this helps.